# Is it possible to perform an ElasticSearch upsert with Jest

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

After looking through the documentation, I am still unsure - If an upsert can be performed against elasticsearch with the Jest java client library?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do so by using the jsonBuilder:

```
new Update.Builder(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().field("doc_as_upsert", true).startObject("doc").field("foo", "bar").string());
```